# Java printing from a printer with App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How is it possible to print from a printer without a dialog box in a Java application using App Engine?
I tried to use `printJob` but I'm getting the following error message:

> java.awt.print.PrinterJob is a restricted class. Please see the Google
>   App Engine developer's guide for more details.

I took a look at the App Engine developer's guide, but didn't find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Many classes that deal with IO and indeed most of java.awt and graphics is not possible to use on App Engine.  Those classes are restricted as your error message indicates.

As for what you are trying to do I think you've missed some core concepts of app engine.

> Google App Engine lets you run web applications on Google's
>   infrastructure.

When you mention dialog box, PrinterJob and printing to a printer it seems to indicate you're not talking about a web application.  A more realistic scenario would be preparing a pdf or similar that the client browser prints or an application that over http collects then prints locally.